# Implementing custom 2FA with Firebase Blocking Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase with identity platform supports 2FA out of the box with an sms. There is not much progress on supporting other 2FA methods so we want to implement our own.

Using Blocking Functions we let the user sign in with the email and password. Then in `beforeSignIn` throw an error back to the user:

```
const beforeSignIn = functions
  .auth.user()
  .beforeSignIn(async (user, context) => {
    const userAuth = await admin.firestore().collection("user").doc(user.uid).get()
    if (userAuth.data().multifactorType === 'authenticator') {
      console.log(`User [${user.uid}] requires 2FA with authenticator`);
    
      const loginAttempt = {eventId: context.eventId, timestamp: Timestamp.now()}
      await admin.firestore().collection('user').doc(user.uid).update({multifactorLoginAttempt: loginAttempt})
      const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'top-secret-key').update(user.uid).update(context.eventId).digest('hex');
      throw new functions.auth.HttpsError('failed-precondition', JSON.stringify({ uid: user.uid, hmac }));      
   }
    console.log(`No 2FA in db. User will login`);
});
```

The user get their uid back with a hmac (created as you can see in the code) and are being redirected to a page where the input their OTP from an authenticator app.

Finally our webapp call our servers with the uid, hmac and otp (say `/api/verify-multifactor`). We persisted the eventId (to be sure they completed email/password login) and together with userid and the "top-secret-key" (shared between functions and our server using Googles Secret Manager) we can verify the hmac and using otplib we verify the OTP. If all is ok we sign the user in with:

```
const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId);
```

Now finally the question - should the endpoint (`/api/verify-multifactor`) be secured in any more ways? With both the hmac and the otp we assume there is no easy way to brute-force and get a custom-token, but we really want to be sure we're not missing any thing. Is there any other way to get some kind of temporary token from Firebase Blocking Functions instead of using our "home-made" hmac?

---

EDIT: The `/api/verify-multifactor` route (never mind if it won't compile, just quickly rewrote to simplify):

```
multifactorRoutes.post(
  '/verify',
  async (
    req: Request<{}, {}, MultifactorVerifyType>,
    res: Response<{ token: string } | { message: string }>
  ) => {
    const userId = req.body.uid;

    const user = await auth.firestore().collection("user").doc(userId).get();
    if (!user.multifactorLoginAttempt) {
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'No existing login attempt' });
      return;
    }
    
    const hmacRecreated = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'top-secret-key').update(userId).update(user.multifactorLoginEvent.eventId).digest('hex');
    const isExpectedHmac = crypto.timingSafeEqual(
      Buffer.from(hmacRecreated),
      Buffer.from(req.body.hmac)
    );

    if (!isExpectedHmac) {
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'Failed to verify hmac' });
      return;
    }
    
    /** using otplib **/
    const isValidOtp = authenticator.verify({
      token: req.body.token,
      secret: user.secret,
    });
    
    if (isValidOtp) {
      const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId);
      await admin.firestore().collection('user').doc(userId).update({ multifactorLoginAttempt: deleteValue() });
      res.status(200).send({ token });
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'Illegal token' });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: It's really hard to say when you've provided almost no information about how the `verify-multifactor` endpoint works. The code sample you provided for the blocking function is essentially irrelevant; it's the code for the actual endpoint you want protected that would matter.

Comment: FYI, the `HttpsError` constructor can take three arguments - [`HttpsError(code, message, details)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https.httpserror#httpshttpserrorconstructor). It would make more sense to provide the extra info in the details using `new HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'Needs 2FA', { uid: user.uid, hmac })`. This will make auditing this error easier because your error message is actually an error message.